# html angularjs live edit feature in chrome browser?

Tags: html, angularjs, google-chrome

I have been practicing angularjs tuts from various tutorials,

I ran across a video tutorial which shows/depicts the live edit of html+angularjs in chrome browser

I am bit amazed with the feature , i am searching for the same since a day and unable to get any such feature,

Alterntatively i tried with webstrom7 which is bit buggy not working with chrome properly on frequent occasions, I know that brackets.io does implement such feature but i would be appreciating the below chrome live edit.

**can anyone identify this live editor feature from the pic and suggest the best way to grab it for windows box - is the below a plugin ?**

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Is Batarang. a Chrome Extension!

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en